# Sorting of vector containing structure

Tags: c++

I was trying to sort a vector of struct.The following is my code.I am not able to sort it properly...Can anyone help me..?I need to sort according to the mmNo.Sorry ...i missed some part of the code...

```
typedef struct MMInfo
{
  std :: string strMmNo;
  std :: string strMmName;
  std :: string strMmsPlace;
  std :: string strMmAdd;
  std :: string strMmPh;

  MMInfo(const std::string& mmNo,
         const std::string& mmName,
         const std::string& mmPlace,
         const std::string& mmAdd,
         const std::string& mmPh) : stringValue(mmNo,),stringValue(mmName),
                                    stringValue(mmPlace),stringValue(mmAdd),
                                    stringValue(mmPh) {}

  bool operator < (const MMInfo& str) const
  {
    return (mmNo < str.mmNo);
  }

} MMInfo;

std::vector < MMInfo > mmlist;
MMInfo mmInfo = {"", "", "", "", ""};

mmInfo.strMmNo = "3452132";   //actually , i have used a loop to get it from the user
mmInfo.strMmName="Peter";
mmInfo.strMmPlace="TCR";
mmInfo.strMmAdd="Street 453";
mmInfo.strMmPh="8587556587";

mmlist.push_back(mmInfo);

sort(mmlist.begin(),mmlist.end());
for (int i=0; i<mmlist.size(); i++)
{
  cout << " first row :" << mmlist[i].strMmNo << " " << mmlist[i].strMmName 
       <<" " <<mmlist[i].strMmsPlace  << " " << mmlist[i].strMmsAdd ;
}
```

Comment: Why?  What is not happening "properly"?

Comment: This code doesn't even compile. Is the question why it doesn't compile?

Comment: `mmlist` is empty, so move along, nothing to sort here.

Comment: Or maybe the question is why it sorts according to lexical order instead of numerical order?

Comment: @vidhya: You posted fake non-compilable code and provided no explanation of what's wrong with it. How do you expect someone to answer your question?

Comment: Andrey...actually my code had a function for populating the mmlist which was a long one and i didn't want to really make my question complex by adding that....i just assumed that the sorting will be done after filling the mmlist...really sorry ,for not mentioning that in the question.Now i have added it ...pardon..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has no problems. I mean, the usage is right but the structure definition seems not correct. It's not compilable at least in Visual C++ 9.0 Please make a proper initialization list. The following code worked fine for me

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

typedef struct NodeInfo
{
    int x;

    NodeInfo( int xi ){ x = xi;  }
    bool operator < (const NodeInfo& str) const
    {
        return (x < str.x);
    }
}MMInfo;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector < MMInfo > mmlist;

    mmlist.push_back( 1 );
    mmlist.push_back( 31 );
    mmlist.push_back( 21 );
    mmlist.push_back( 11 );
    mmlist.push_back( 41 );
    sort(mmlist.begin(),mmlist.end());
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<mmlist.size(); i++)
    {
        cout<< " x row : \n" << mmlist[i].x ;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does that even compile? (No!)

- You're trying to initialize values that don't exist. Maybe initialize your `strMm*` values instead of `stringValue`?
- You're initializing the same value (that doesn't even exist!) multiple times (Initialize `strMm*` members with a corresponding `mm*` value)
- Your comparison function compares values that don't exist. (Compare `strMmNo < str.strMmNo`).

Also, you don't even have values to sort in your list.